# Can I save information in message requests with Discord API?

Tags: javascript, post, get, discord, discord.js

I tried to send messages like this

```js
client.api.channels(msg.channel.id).messages.post({
  data: {
    content: 'content',
    test: 'test'
  }
})
```

I was hoping that since it’s an API post request, it would save the `test` property.

```js
const msgs = await client.api.channels(msg.channel.id).messages.get();
msg.channel.send(msgs[1].test) //error: cannot send an empty message
```

Changing `.test` to `.content` *does* send the content of the message the bot sent originally, but `.test` outputs undefined. Maybe I need to use `node-fetch` or `https` so it posts and gets directly?

Comment: You are sending the `test` property to the Discord API via a post request, but that doesn't mean that Discord API will store that property to its database. I think that it only cares about the data it knows and the rest gets dropped. If I were designing an API, I would design it the same way.

Comment: They would have to implement something like you have with Message Components (e.g. a button), the `customId` property, but with messages. If you are aiming for something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the `test` property to the Discord API via a post request, but that doesn't mean Discord API will store that property to its database. It only cares about the data it knows and the rest gets dropped. All properties Discord stores about a message are listed [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object).

**Discord API doesn't allow you to store arbitrary data inside of a message object.**

*<s>Of course you could search for workarounds, like storing the data inside of an embed's color (if they are short enough) or an image, etc. I don't think that is a good solution to this problem, but depends on what you want to accomplish.</s>*

What you could do is to store the custom data yourself. Create some kind of middleware, that will send a message to the Discord API, retrieve the message object of the newly created message. And associate its id with your custom data and store it somewhere (e.g. your database, JSON file, etc.)

Later you can use a message's id to access your custom data.